# JavaScript retornando input vazio

Tags: javascript

Tenho um Formulário onde multiplico duas variáveis nas seguintes condições:

Apenas multiplico a `variavel1` pela `variavel2`, se a `variavel2` for preenchida, caso contrário o campo total será igual a `varialvel1`.

O erro acontece quando tento submeter o formulário e a `variavel2` não está preenchida, ocorre o erro

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.math.BigDecimal for property totalCorrida; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Quando a `variavel2` é preenchida o formulário salva, porém quando ele não é preenchido ocorre o erro.

Já pensei em colocar a `variavel2` com o valor = 1, porém como sou novato em JavaScript não tenho ideia de como retornar o `valortotal` mais o valor 1 para a `variavel2`.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>    
  <form>
    <input id="valor1" onblur="calcular()"><br>
    <input id="valor2" onblur="calcular()"><br>
    <input id="total"><br>
    <button type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código JavaScript

```
function calcular(){
    var valor1 = (document.getElementById('valor1').value);
    var valor2 = (document.getElementById('valor2').value);

    var total;       

    if (valor2==null || valor2==""){
        total = valor1;

        return document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }else {
        valor1 = parseFloat(valor1.replace(',','.'));
        valor2 = parseFloat(valor2.replace(',','.'));

        total = valor1 * valor2;
        return document.getElementById('total').value = total;    
    }
}
```

Comment: O erro não tem nada a ver com JavaScript, ele **é no servidor**. Tá escrito ali **`java.lang.NumberFormatException`**. E também, tá bem claro que **não foi possível converter** um valor `String` para `java.math.BigDecimal` na propriedade `totalCorrida`.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo que foi servidor quem validou o submit, mas não seria possível eu enviar via javascript o valor total + o valor2 = 1? isso já resolveria meu problema.